# Need to get truck tranny fixed

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, avalanche

Have 05 avalanche tranny out given a fresh good one out of 99 Silverado.  What am I gonna have to do to get it to work in my truck.  1 vehicle. Avalanche is 1500 2wd 5.3 plugs are different on shift 99 has 2 mine has 1.  Also new ones shift using the speed sensor on rt side back.  What to do ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds to me like you need to get a different transmission. I don't think there is an easy way to adapt the transmission you got to your Avalanche. Besides the electronics plug, there could also be differences in where your flexplate holds the torque converter. If it is in the wrong place, it can easily kill the front pump on the new-to-you transmission. Your best bet is to get one which is matched to your year of truck.